# C# - Parallel.Foreach() for Service Call

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, parallel.foreach, .net-4.6.1

I have a console application which does 3 steps as mentioned below,

1. Get pending notification records from db
2. Call service to send email (service returns email address as response)
3. After getting service response, update the db

For step 2, I am using *Parallel.Foreach()* and it is working far better than *foreach()*.
I have gone through lot of articles and threads on stackoverflow which is causing more confusion on this topic. 
I have few questions

1. I am running this on a server, does it affect the performance and should I limit the number of threads? (The email count can be from 0-500 or 1000)
2. I ran into one issue, where in step 2, the service returned an email address as response but it was not available while updating the db. (email count here was 400)
   I am suspecting that the issue could be because of using parallel.foreach and that it did not add in *notifList*.
   If this is the case, can I add Thread.Sleep(1000) after Parallel.Foreach() loop ends, does it fix the issue?
3. In case of any exception, should I explicitly cancel the threads?

*Appreciate your time and effort on helping me with this. Thank you!*

```
public void notificationMethod()
{
    List<notify> notifList = new List<notify>();

    //step 1
    List<orders> orderList = GetNotifs();

    try
    {
        if (orderList.Count > 0)
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(orderList, (orderItem) =>
            {
               //step 2
               SendNotifs(orderItem);
                notifList.Add(new notify()
               {
                   //building list by adding email address along with other information
               });
            });
            if (notifList.Count > 0)
            {
                int index = 0; 
                int rows = 10; 
                int skipRows = index * rows;
                int updatedRows = 0;
                while (skipRows < notifList.Count)
                {
                    //pagination 
                    List<notify> subitem = notifList.Skip(index * rows).Take(rows).ToList<notify>();
                    updatedRows += subitem.Count;

                    //step 3
                    UpdateDatabase(subitem);

                    index++;
                    skipRows = index * rows;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ApplicationException ex)
    {
    }            
}
```

Comment: I think you should be using one of the specialised concurrent collection types (for notifList), rather than List<T>, I would go with ConcurrentBag<T> and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: In addition to @StewartRitchie comment, I recommend you also use the Task Parallel Library for this. The library does most of the thread management for you, and there are ways to catch and handle exceptions per request. No threading is directly involved so it's generally safer to use as well. Then, you can use ```await foreach()``` to run these in parallel. [Review the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) for further details.

Comment: @NikP If they're using `Parallel.ForEach`, they're already using the TPL. Is there something more specific in there you're referencing?

Comment: @digitlworld yes, specifically wrapping the individual calls in tasks and using the TAP patterns, and following exception handling advice [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-parallel-loops). The gist is finer control over which exceptions are caught where and how they are handled, so if one of the 1000 calls throws, it doesn't muck up the rest and you can trace the failed call to figure out why.

Comment: To expand on what @StewartRitchie mentioned: `List<T>` is *not* thread-safe.  If multiple threads add items concurrently you're definitely likely to lose some.  `ConcurrentBag<T>` *is* thread-safe.

Comment: @NikP, Thank you for your inputs. I have made couple of changes to the code.But, there are very limited examples for Parallel.Foreach with <Task>. I made the following changes. 

var task = Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(lstOrderHeaders, (orderItem) =>  { }); });
task.Wait();

Comment: @StewartRitchie, ConcurrentBag seemed to help in my case. Thank you so much ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar scenario regarding whether using `Parallel.ForEach()` would help improve the performance. But when I saw the below video from Microsoft, it gave me an idea to select `Parallel.ForEach()` *only* for CPU intensive workloads.
In this case, your scenario will fall into I/O intensive workloads and could be handled better by `async`/`await`.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Tip-2-Distinguish-CPU-Bound-work-from-IO-bound-work